# What happens when Error is thrown?

Tags: java, error-handling

My fellow's API's static initialization got some bug and was throwing me ExceptionInInitializerError. found this while catching a throwable.What happens when ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown? Because It didn't get caught or the the control return. The execution went on,with skipping rest of the execution.Below is the skeleton of my code.

```
for(...) {
   // pre callings statements
   callsAnExtrenalAPI();
}

//inside callsAnExtrenalAPI implementation 

try {
      //Some miscellaneous code that caused the error
      // Some good stuff which is never called
    }catch(Exception e){
      // Error Logging which is never called here.
    }
```

what happens when an Error is thrown? Either code has stopped or indicated the error in any form.

Comment: read this for example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

The `ExceptionInInitializerError` is a sub-class of the `LinkageError` class and denotes that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

To get more information about the exception you can call `getException()` method

Answer (score 0):

when `ExceptionInInitializerError`  thrown and not catch by the catch block then that exception/error should be propagate to the invoker.

> If invoked by main() then exception passed to the system/jvm and will
>   cause to the terminate whole execution.